# Excel 2010 comparing multiple columns (2 columns to 2 other columns)

Tags: excel, comparison, compare, excel-2010

I want to compare 2 columns to 2 other columns.

The thing is that I want to be able to search the whole column for the second set of 2 columns. For instance, values in `C2 and D2` could match values in `I23 and J23` or `I101 and J101`.

I found out about VLOOKUP having that feature for comparing one column to another.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2;$I$2:$K$343;3)
```

In the function above, C2 value is looked up into I column (from cell 2 to 343) and if found in that column, it'll return the value of the 3rd cell at the right of the matching cell.

Combined with this question's answer [How to compare multiple columns in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490199/how-to-compare-multiple-columns-in-excel) that could work but I'm looking for a "clean" way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a User Defined Function that will perform a 2 column lookup. Treat it like a `vlookup`.

`LookupPair` is a pair of cells. (C2:D2) in your example. Anything other that a pair of side-by-side cells will cause an error.

`LookupRange` is the columns that include both the matching pair columns **and** the return column. Something like (I1:K101) in your example. `LookupRange` must contain at least two columns or an error is generated.

`ReturnCol` is the column number in `LookupRange` that contains the value to be returned. (same as `Col_index_num` in a `vlookup`).

The function only does exact matches.

```
Function DoubleColMatch(LookupPair As Range, LookupRange As Range, ReturnCol As Integer) As Variant
Dim ReturnVal As Variant
Dim Col1Val As Variant
Dim Col2Val As Variant
Dim x As Long

    If LookupPair.Rows.Count > 1 _
    Or LookupPair.Columns.Count <> 2 _
    Or LookupRange.Columns.Count < 2 _
    Or ReturnCol < 1 _
    Or ReturnCol > LookupRange.Columns.Count _
    Then
        ReturnVal = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Else
        Col1Val = LookupPair.Cells(1, 1)
        Col2Val = LookupPair.Cells(1, 2)

        ReturnVal = CVErr(xlErrNA)

        For x = 1 To LookupRange.Rows.Count
            If LookupRange.Cells(x, 1) = Col1Val _
            And LookupRange.Cells(x, 2) = Col2Val Then
                ReturnVal = LookupRange.Cells(x, ReturnCol).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x

    End If

    DoubleColMatch = ReturnVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple variant would be to use the function CONCATENATE() to concatenate a search string from the two columns. Afterwards you can compare the columns with various functions VLOOKUP(), MATCH().....